# Recyclerview only showing first value

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, kotlin

i am having an issue with my gson parsing. I have a nested gson and i would like get the value of "name" under attributes.  The problem is my recyclerview is only showing the first value(which is bill 1) and not bill 2 or bill 3. here is my code

```
// MainActivity.kt
    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    recycler_view.addItemDecoration(LineItemDecorator(requireContext()))
    val bill = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString, Bills::class.java)
            val nameList: List<Bill> = Arrays.asList(bill)
            val adapter = BillsRecyclerAdapter(nameList)
            recycler_view.adapter = adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

// Bills.kt
    data class Bills(
        val data: ArrayList<Data>,
        val meta: Meta,
        val links: Links
    )

// BillsRecyclerAdapter.kt
    class BillsRecyclerAdapter(private val items: List<Bill>):
            RecyclerView.Adapter<BillsRecyclerAdapter.BillsHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BillsHolder {
            return BillsHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.bills_list_item))
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BillsHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.billName.text = items[position].data[position].attributes.name       
        }


        override fun getItemCount() = items.size

        class BillsHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            val billName: TextView = view.billName
            val billAmount: TextView = view.billAmount
        }
    }

<!-- recyclerview.xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/materialize_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- bill_list_item.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billAmount"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my json string. https://pastebin.com/iEqhmB35

thanks for any help provided

Comment: Can you please post your XML file. I think i know the answer.

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

1. Check your `items.size` if it really is not zero,
2. Also check your `bills_list_item.xml` try to set the root parent's height to `wrap_content`
3. Also check if you have this on you `recyclerview`

   ```
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
   ```
4. What's important there is the layout manager

If it doesn't help, can you share your `Bills.java` class, there might be something wrong with the serialization of JSON raw data.

Hope this helps. 
Cheers

Comment: My Bills.java is in the OP. My items.size() is 1(which is not right)

Comment: i think your doing just fine, what wrong there is the Bill.java class holds the data array. so instead of using Bill as list, use Bill.data.size() check your json, its parsing the data array object and saving the bill as one.